# Is it possible to convert a rosh of a Rabeynu Tam Tefillin into a rosh of a Rashi Tefillin?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, rashi, rabbeinu-tam

If I find a Rabeynu Tam Tefillin and I do not have another one, can I take it apart, and change the *rosh* (I know how to) from Rabeynu Tam to a Rashi Tefillin?

Comment: Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for the fascinating question! Please consider registering your account, to help the site keep track of your contributions.

Comment: Are you asking whether it is legal or whether it is physically possible/feasible?

Comment: @Danny Any reason to capitalise "Tefillin"?

Answer (score 11):

You are not allowed to.  This is because the two opinions mutually invalidate one another and therefore you would be taking Kosher Tefillin and making it not Kosher according to Rabbeinu Tam. This is considered to be Mezalzel in the shita of Rabbeinu Tam. See the Ridvaz Chelek-6 Siman 2286.

Comment: The Ridvaz says he first ruled it was permissible, then had a bad dream so he changed his mind. Weird. IAE this would only seem to apply to someone who treats RT's opinion as not nidche lehalacha.

Answer (score 2):

This is Asur because it goes under the category "Maalim BikDusha WeLo Moridin." (Od Yosef Hai Wayera #8. see Oserot Yosef 3:6).

Comment: Your answer is unclear. Are you stating that the temporary posul status when the tefilla is disassembled is a yerida? Or that Rashi tefillin are somehow "less kadosh" than RT?